# Hibernate ForeignKey mapping annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to have hibernate generate some tables with foreign keys and so on. Ill give you an example of the query i want hibernate to generate:

```
create table RealtimeCost(id INTEGER not null primary key Autoincrement,
    mnemonic varchar(50)not null references Exchange(mnemonic),
    sid int not null references License(sid),
    price numeric(10,2) not null)
```

so this query should be generated by hibernate via Annotations. The corresponding class to this is:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class RealtimeCost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @MapsId("mnemonic")
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="sid")
    private String mnemonic;
    @MapsId("sid")
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="sid")
    private Integer sid;
    @Column
    private Double price;
```

Example for what the `mnemonic` in `RealtimeCost` should be mapped to (each mnemonic in `RealtimeCost` has exactly 1 value in `Exchange`):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Exchange {
    @Id
    @Column(name="mnemonic")
    private String exchange;
    @Column
    private String description;
```

As you can see I've tried a bit with the help of the docs, but I was not able to have the foreign keys be generated by hibernate. It would be really kind, if anyone could tell me the needed annotations and values for this class, so i can do it myself for the other classes as well. Also please tell me if i need to change anything in the `Exchange` class for the mapping to work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert but we let hibernate do all the work with the javax.persistence annotations for joining entities.

```
  @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = true )
  @javax.persistence.JoinColumn( name = "VIEWTYPE_ID", nullable = true, unique = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
  private com.company.other.subproject.ViewType viewType;
```

Maybe this is what you need. Since this let's hibernate care about the tables that have to be created or not and the foreignKeys get created automatically with the dialect of the database you communicate with.

Comment: does this map an object of type `ViewType` to only the id of the class `ViewType`?

Comment: can you tell me how you annotated viewtype id?

Comment: Sorry for the late Answer. Yes it mappes the entity as ID reference. With the FetchType you can specify further how it should be loaded. (Lazy or Eager)
The ViewType is annotated with this `@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride( name = "id", column = @Column( name = "VIEWTYPE_ID" ) )
} )` but this annotation is at the Class definition. since we use another strategy of declaring entities. But the id column is Annotated with @Id.

This is an example annotation for the fetchtype `@javax.persistence.Basic( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER, optional = false )`

Answer (score 2):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "accommodation_type", unique = true, nullable = false)
private AccommodationType accommodationType;
```

`@ManyToOne()`creates a relationship according to `@JoinColumn()`
`name` in `@JoinColumn()` is the table name that you want to make a connection.

Then when you create a class that is going to be connected to main class, you first need to give it a table name below `@Entity` e.g `@Table(name="accommodation_types")`

Then you create your variable.

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Accommodation
@OneToMany(mappedBy="accommodationType", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Accommodation> accommodations;
```

value of `mappedBy`is the variable name in main class.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up the association in one entity and use the `mappedBy` in the other. You don't need `@MapsId` because you are not using embedded entities (read the docs). Take a look at the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relationships:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class RealtimeCost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="mnemonic")
    private Exchange exchange;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Exchange {
    @Id
    @Column(name="mnemonic")
    private String mnemonic;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy="exchange")
    private RealtimeCost realtimeCost;
    ...
}
```

Comment: this `@ManyToOne(mappedBy="exchange")` causes an error for me `The attribute mappedBy is undefined for the annotation type ManyToOne`

Answer (score 1):

Every answer posted here got an upvote from me, because everyone was kinda right, but it was not 100% what i was searching for, yet it helped me solving my problem by myself. For the example i posted, the solution i was seeking is as follows (i also added not nullable):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class RealtimeCost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mnemonic",nullable=false)
    private Exchange exchange;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sid",nullable=false)
    private License license;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Double price;
```

these are the annotations i was seeking for `RealtimeCost` class. I did not need any special annotations in Exchange class. @Nico answer was closest to what i need, therefore his answer will be accepted